# How can i import the psd file and generate layers in framerjs

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I am using windows and i have my psd file.i want to create a interactive prototype using framerjs. i have atom text editor and i have downloaded framerjs from `http://framerjs.com/static/downloads/Framer.zip`

now how to import the design file into and generate the layers using the framer generator in windows?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Framer studio,

Think you need the Photoshop to be running with the psd file open.

Found the below text on Framer github - https://github.com/koenbok/Framer

```
Framer Generator

With a Sketch or Photoshop file open, open Framer Generator and click Import. Only layer groups are imported; single layers are ignored. The hierarchy of your layer groups is respected.

You can safely move things around in Sketch or Photoshop and re-import. Generator will update the images and any changes in hierarchy, but leave your code intact. See our documentation for more.

Access any layer by its group name
Groups within groups will become subLayers
Groups with vector masks will become clipped layers
Group names should be unique (otherwise, they'll be renamed)
```